# Check if ruby script finished successfully

Tags: ruby

I want to write script in ruby. I would like that script will return true or false. Is it possible? Can I return value from ruby script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! [`Kernel.exit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) takes an optional argument. Put this into `exit.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "Hello, world"
exit 1
```

Verify like so:

```
$ ruby exit.rb ; echo $?
Hello, world
1
```

Comment: Note that `true` is normally `0`, and `false` anything else, for purpose of testing in shell, opposite from what you'd expect from most programming languages. Specifically, `/bin/true` returns `0`, and `/bin/false` returns `1`.

Comment: And how can I get that value? I mean in console.

Comment: If you want to inspect the return code, look at `$?`. If you want to use it in, say, `if`, you directly put the statement in `if`: `if ruby is_bigger_than.rb 2 4; then echo "2 bigger than 4"; else echo "2 not bigger than 4"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. For ruby, the value of the last expression is the default return value.

For example:

```
2.1.2 :001 > def test
2.1.2 :002?>   true
2.1.2 :003?>   end
 => :test
2.1.2 :004 > test
 => true
2.1.2 :005 > def test1
2.1.2 :006?>   false
2.1.2 :007?>   end
 => :test1
2.1.2 :008 > test1
 => false
2.1.2 :009 > def test2
2.1.2 :010?>   100
2.1.2 :011?>   end
 => :test2
2.1.2 :012 > test2
 => 100
```

Comment: This is the value of a function/block, not a value of a script. Scripts return value using `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Run a ruby script, it will return a true/false value to tell command if it run success or fail.
At the end of you rb file, add a judge code to tell command if rb file run success:

```
if @success
  return true
else
  raise "RuntimeError"
end
```

Cover `@success` as you condition, when error occure, run script will return false, eles true